# Can't add particular repo as a submodule

Tags: git, submodule

I'm switching to using submodules for my vim plugins. The usual way of doing this is:

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/vim-scripts/a.vim bundle/a.vim
Cloning into 'bundle/a.vim'...
etc, etc
```

This works fine with every plugin but Gundo:

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim bundle/gundo
```

There is no output from running this command. The repo is added to .gitmodules and `bundle/gundo` is created, but is empty except for a `.git` file.

```
$ cd bundle/gundo
$ git status
# On branch (null)
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

I'm completely new to submodules. What is special about this repository and how do I correctly add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's going on exactly, but it might be useful if you check/provide the output of the following:

```
cd bundle/gundo
git remote -v
```

If the output shows that the repo has the correct origin, then it might just be that you need to checkout the master branch, ie:

```
cd bundle/gunco
git fetch
git checkout master
```

If the submodule is still messed up and everything fails, you can try to remove the broken submodule and all traces of it from your repo. You can do this by running the following commands from the toplevel of your git working tree:

```
git config -f .git/config --remove-section submodule.bundle/gundo
git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.bundle/gundo
git rm --cached bundle/gundo
rm -rf .git/modules/bundle/gundo
rm -rf bundle/gundo
```

After this, check `git status` to make sure everything looks normal. Then attempt to create the submodule again.

If none of this works, then try adding your git version (run: `git --version`) and your config (run: `git config -l`) to the question as they might help others figure out what's going on.

P.S: You don't need to paste the entire output of `git config -l`, and you should probably remove/mask-out user.name, user.email and any other data that you don't want to share on the internet.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks! Completely removing the submodule according to your steps did the trick. I'm not 100% sure, but I think I entered the repository url incorrectly the first time. I tried earlier to remove all traces, but I wasn't thorough enough.